# How to access files after committing them in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git

So I have changes to my code as I am working locally on a newer version of my project and had to commit my changes so I can pull and merge changes from my master branch (there were minor changes on the master version of the project that I needed to add to my code and they were done by a different developer so they were pushed to the branch directly.

But now I need to access the files (or stage the commits) so I can copy the changes I made (I didn't push them to the branch) as files. Normally I undo last commit which would return my files to staged changes but I have 3 commits and one of them is a merge commit (merge code from master to my code locally).

How can I access my files without deleting the changes?

Comment: if you have a merge commit due to the pull your local changes should be in the merged file. You can push this merge commit to the remote repository

Answer (score 0):

So basically few commands you can check:

you can do soft(after reset will keep changes locally) reset

```
git reset --soft HEAD~{number of commits}
```

you can do hard(after reset will NOT keep changes locally) reset

```
git reset --hard HEAD~{number of commits}
```

PS:
If you want to stash your changes locally and take a pull and if all fine apply your stash changes.

```
git stash save name
```

if you want to show all stash list

```
git stash list
```

if you want to apply the stash changes:

```
git stash apply stash{tag}
```

But what you have done if I understood correctly:

Try these and please read a bit about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inspect the content of a file in a given commit without checking out that file, you can use `git show` :

```
git show <commit>:path/to/file
git show <commit>:path/to/file > tempfile.txt
```